Strange work of cur.executescript operator with placeholder
I'm trying to use cur.executescript operator with INSERT statement with placeholder
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('SingleTableSql.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Track (title TEXT, plays INTEGER)')

cur.executescript("""
    INSERT INTO Track (title, plays) VALUES (?, ?), ('Thunderstruck', 20);
    INSERT INTO Track (title, plays) VALUES (?, ?), ('My Way', 15);
""")

conn.commit()
cur.execute('SELECT title, plays FROM Track')
for row in cur:
    print(row)
cur.close()

But result of work is very strange.
(None, None)
('Thunderstruck', 20)
(None, None)
('My Way', 15)

Why? How to fix?
Expected result is
('Thunderstruck', 20)
('My Way', 15)

Python 3.12

You are mixing up the "pure" sqlite syntax and sqlite3 from Python.
executescript expects "pure" sqlite syntax but you are providing smt similar to that of executemany.
Any queries containing placeholders should be executed by either executemany or execute and the data for the placeholder should be passed as parameter, see methods of Cursor for details and/or the implementations below.
(?, ?) are understood as data to be inserted in the database which will become the (None, None) records.
sql-multivalue insertions are comma-separated
sql_script = """-- single command
INSERT INTO Track (title, plays) 
VALUES ('Thunderstruck', 20),
       ('My Way', 15);"""

or as two distinct commands
sql_script = """-- multiple commands
INSERT INTO Track (title, plays) VALUES ('Thunderstruck', 20);
INSERT INTO Track (title, plays) VALUES ('My Way', 15);
"""

and the pass it to executescript
cur.executescript(sql_script)


Alternatively, using executemany and sqlite3 placeholders:

case qmark style placeholders

records = ('Thunderstruck', 20), ('My Way', 15)
cur.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO Track (title, plays) VALUES (?, ?);", 
    records
    )


case named style placeholder

records = {'title': 'Thunderstruck', 'plays': 20}, {'title': 'My Way', 'plays': 15}
cur.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO Track VALUES (:title, :plays) ;", 
    records
    )


They're not using executemany syntax. They put the Python tuples inside the SQL string.

Maybe I wrote my explanation a bit bad... what I mean is that cur.executescript("INSERT INTO Track (title, plays) VALUES (?, ?);") is the cause of the (None, None) entries in the database. For ex the following query is valid as well "INSERT INTO Track (title, plays) VALUES ('Thunderstruck', 20), ('My Way', 15);"

are the placeholder notations supported by executescript?

No, it's not. That's probably why they thought they had to put the values inside the SQL string, because it couldn't be added separately.

Ok, that's why I wanted to fix such ambiguity by showing the two cases

My comment was just addressed to this point "you are proving that of executemany". "proving" looks like a typo for "providing", but they're not providing the input of executemany because it doesn't have the parameter values in the middle of the string.

Sorry for the misunderstanding. You are right, I also saw (and fixed) it in my last edit. Hope it's clearer:)
